# Simpler way to display badgeOS thumbnails with custom URL

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, simplify

Good day,
My limited knowledge of php has ended up creating a monstrosity of code. I am hoping someone could show me a simpler, cleaner way to accomplish this. Unfortunately I'm really **really** bad with php.

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

I am trying to code in some badgeOS icons for my Wordpress site that link to corresponding lesson posts. In other words, the thumbnail from  badge_post_id should link to a specific lesson_post_id. The badge thumbnail also needs to have a different look for 'earned' and 'unearned'.

I have the following code that each badge thumbnail currently uses:

```
<!-- Badge must either be marked earned or unearned -->
<?php if (in_array($badge_post_id, $earned_achievements)) {
    $css_class = 'earned-badge'; }
else {
    $css_class = 'unearned-badge'; }
?>

<!-- Each badge requires this code -->
<span id="lesson-#" class="badge-class">
    <a href="http://example.com/?p=$lesson_post_id" class="badge-link">
        <span class="badge-icon">
            <?php echo badgeos_get_achievement_post_thumbnail($badge_post_id, $image_size, $css_class) ;?>
        </span>
        <span class="badge-name"> LESSON TITLE </span>
    </a>
</span>
```

I'm also using this at the start of the page:

```
<!-- Everything gets this -->
<?php
    $image_size = array(100,100);
    $earned_achievements = badgeos_get_user_earned_achievement_ids(get_current_user_id());
?>
```

As you can see, for 30+ badges this is a TON of code, and a huge headache to keep track of.

Ideally it would pull all the needed info from some kind of table (perhaps an array of some kind) that relates all this info:

Lesson number: `$badge_post_id, $lesson_post_id, $lesson_title, $css_class` (earned or unearned)

So I can type someone much simpler to get each badge instead of adding 100 lines of code.

Comment: Here is a pastebin showing the mess a little differently [link](http://pastebin.com/7tq2Yht0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$earned_achivements = badgeos_get_user_earned_achivement_ids();
$badges = get_badges();


foreach ($badges as $badge){
    if (in_array($badge["id"], $earned_achievements)) {
        echo '<span id="lesson-'.$badge["lesson_id"].'" class="earned-badge">';
        $badge_output = badgeos_get_achievement_post_thumbnail( $badge["id"], $image_size, 'earned-badge' );
    } else {
        echo '<span id="lesson-'.$badge["lesson_id"].'" class="unearned-badge">';
        $badge_output = badgeos_get_achievement_post_thumbnail( $badge["id"], $image_size, 'unearned-badge' );
    }
    echo '<a href="http://example.com/?p='.$badge["lesson_id"].'" class="badge-link">';
    echo '<span class="badge-icon">';
    echo $badge_output;
    echo '</span><span class="badge-name">'.$badge["lesson_title"].'</span>';
    echo '</a></span>';
}
```

$badges could be a raw grab of a db table with columns id, lesson_id, lesson_title and whatever else you need.

Comment: Thanks @hendr1x This look very promising indeed! I'm not sure how I could make a table with that information. Is that just another array?

Comment: You can store the data any way you see fit.  An array would be fine for 30 badges....I would use a mysql table and do a db query.

Answer (score 0):

@hendr1x
Your help led to me to this solution! Rather than enter the data in an array or table to be only used once, I used your code and placed it as a function.

```
    function badgeosm($lesson_id, $badge_id){

        $image_size = array(100,100);
        $earned_achievements = badgeos_get_user_earned_achievement_ids( get_current_user_id() );
        $css_class = 'unearned-badge'; // Set unearned-badge as the default.

        if (in_array($badge_id, $earned_achievements)) {
                $css_class = 'earned-badge';
            }
        echo '<span id="lesson-ID-'.$lesson_id.'" class="badge-class">';
        echo '<a href="http://example.com/?p='.$lesson_id.'" class="badge-link">';
        echo '<span class="badge-icon">';
        echo badgeos_get_achievement_post_thumbnail( $badge_id, $image_size, $css_class );
        echo '</span>';
        echo '<span class="badge-name">';
        echo get_the_title( $lesson_id );
        echo '</span>';
        echo '</a>';

    }
badgeosm(1961,1770);
```

Now I just enter the id of the lesson and badge, and the function does the rest. It seems to work well, and it certainly reduces code. Thanks so much. :)